# How to go from Worksheet to SpreadsheetDocument?

Tags: excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

My OpenXML SDK-based application iterates through workbooks and inside that, through worksheets.

I would like to factor out the retrieval of the worksheet.

Given a `Spreadsheet.Worksheet`, how do I find its parent `Packaging.SpreadsheetDocument`?

Through Ancestor, perhaps?

TIA

Update:

The following code has been suggested by Jesper:

```
WorksheetPart worksheetPart   = worksheet.WorksheetPart;
OpenXmlPackage openXmlPackage = worksheetPart.OpenXmlPackage;
SpreadsheetDocument document  = (SpreadsheetDocument) openXmlPackage;
```

That seems to be the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WorkSheet` has a `WorkSheetPart` property

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.worksheet_properties(v=office.14).aspx

`WorkSheetPart` inherits from `OpenXmlPart` which again has an `OpenXmlPackage` property, giving the "root" `OpenXmlPackage` of this `WorkSheetPart`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.worksheetpart(v=office.14).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.worksheetpart_properties(v=office.14).aspx

Can you use that?

Comment: Jasper: I have not tried your suggestion with actual code, but at least it compiles, which is great news. See expressions above in my question.